# How to map the make_remote_executor() method defined on the client from the server- tff.framework.create_executor_factor(make_remote_executor)

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I am still a beginner in federated learning- I would like to clarify my understanding in a remote client-server scenario given the remote_executor_example.py.

[image: REMOTE_SERVICE_CLARIFY]

I hope the image is clear, Kindly clarify if the above components are in the right place in the context of a remote client-server scenario.

If the above understanding is correct, else please correct me:

how do we map the factory to the remote- 'make_remote_executor()' method on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

If I follow the question correctly, I believe the client side should be passing what execution stack it wants to run locally (e.g.[`tff.framework.local_executor_factory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/framework/local_executor_factory)) to [`tff.simulation.run_server`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/run_server).

The clients shouldn't be creating remote executors, those issue gRPC requests to the service, which delegates to a local execution stack.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response. I have modified the flow below :
[image]

'tff.framework.local_executor_factory' has a server_tf_device argument to it. Is that how we link the local_executors to the server running remotely? If so , how ?

My understanding now is that :
Client : creates local_executors using 'tff.framework.local_executor_factory' and connects to  'tff.simulation.run_server'
Server : creates remote_executors that talk to the local_executors on the clients.

Is this understanding correct? How do we map the local_executors on the client to the remote server ?